# Error stopping profiler in plsql developer

Tags: plsql-developer

I am checking on an performance issue and when I try to execute the time consuming query after turning on the profiler, after like a minute it gives the error "Error stopping profiler" and no data is available in the profiler report.

Could someone tell how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.